# Is Sikuli IDE available for 64-bit Windows?

Tags: installation, 64-bit, sikuli, sikuli-ide

Currently, I am using 64-bit Windows and installed Sikuli successfully. But, I'm unable to run the code. Please provide me the link for downloading Sikuli IDE for 64-bit Windows. I am getting this error

> Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform

Please help me out on this

Comment: Yes, it's available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the SikuliX download from here. Its a complete package with IDE and works fine for me.
http://www.sikulix.com/download.html

Comment: [action] ResourceLoaderBasic: checkLibsDir: Please wait! Trying to add it to user's path
[info] runcmd: reg QUERY HKCU 
[info] runcmd: reg QUERY HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment /v PATH 
[error] ResourceLoaderBasic: checkLibsDir: Logout and Login again! (Since libs folder is in user's path, but not activated)
[error] Terminating SikuliX after a fatal error! Sorry, but it makes no sense to continue!
If you do not have any idea about the error cause or solution, run again
with a Debug level of 3. You might paste the output to the Q&A board.

Comment: Thanks for the info, now, am able to run the script but, it shows above error: please help me out on this

Comment: Which package did you choose during the installation?

Comment: 4 and 6.  I am not sure which package, I have to choose.

Comment: For basic requirements package 1 should be the right choose. Try log out and log in again. Did you install the stable build or beta? Here is more info on this error: https://answers.launchpad.net/sikuli/+question/234720

Comment: I have installed package 1. here, I have to use sikuli jar. which one i have to use. should i use sikuli - ide.jar. Can I run it using JUnit or TestNG. Please help me.  Thank you

Comment: For programming and testing you would probably prefer the ide.jar
For unit testing have a look at the faq section here: http://doc.sikuli.org/

Comment: AFter Log in and loggged out. it is working fine. Thank you for your comments. I have set the code to click on Go button, it is clicking and I have to check whether it is landing in the correct page after clicking on "Go" button. Can you pls suggest me more scripts for this. pls help me out. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The error means that **you're running a 64-bit process**. 64-bit processes can only load 64-bit DLLs and 32-bit process can only load 32-bit DLLs. So you already have the 64-bit version of Sikuli

Comment: Thanks for the info. How to get this. Can you pls provide me link for Sikuli IDE 64?

Comment: you're already running 64-bit application. I don't know you want to load the IDE's dll or your application's dll. If the loader is your program then you need a 64-bit compiler